# How do you change your Solana CLI version?

Tags: cli

If I want to change my Solana CLI version to an older version, how do I do that via the CLI?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to change your current installed Solana CLI version, just type the following command:

```
solana-install init <VERSION>
```

where `<VERSION>` is the desired CLI version to install.